# installing Freeglut on Linux

Tags: c, linux, opengl, linux-mint, freeglut

I am trying to install freeglut on my computer running Linux Mint. I follow the steps on this website: http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/install.php. When I do `make all` in the src directory, it gives the following error:

`fatal error: GL/gl.h`

This error was given by ../include/GL/freeglut_std.h. Upon inspection, the include/GL directory is indeed devoid of any gl.h file. It is also missing glu.h, which freeglut_std.h also tries to `#include`. What should I do about this? Why are gl.h and glu.h missing?

Comment: Did you run `make` before or after the [`configure`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configure_script_%28computing%29) script?  `configure` should have informed you of the missing headers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd recommend installing the `freeglut3-dev` package instead of building from source.  That will give you useful stuff like automatic updates and proper [`pkg-config`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) entries that you can reference in your `make`files.

If you're dead-set on building freeglut from source you'll probably need the `libgl1-mesa-dev` and (maybe) `libglu1-mesa-dev` packages.

Comment: so what are freeglut3-dev and pkg-config? How do I install freeglut3-dev once I've downloaded it? And how does pkg-config assist in installing freeglut?

Comment: `freeglut3-dev` is a Debian [package](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/freeglut3-dev) name.  Mint is Debian/Ubuntu-based.  You should be able to install it via `sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev`.

Comment: As the linked Wiki article says: "pkg-config is computer software that provides a unified interface for querying installed libraries for the purpose of compiling software from its source code."

Comment: `pkg-config` won't assist in installing `freeglut` though it will assist in *using* it.

Comment: It [doesn't seem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017325/why-freeglut3-dev-doesnt-provide-pc-file-for-pkg-config) to be true on *Linux Debian*. There is no [.pc](http://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html#concepts) file in [freeglut3-dev](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/freeglut3-dev) package for [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config).

Comment: @patryk.beza: [Fixed 12 years later!](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=575025#10)  See the `glut.pc` in [`libglut-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libglut-dev).

Comment: @genpfault  https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/14a5ul7/this_is_the_standard_operating_procedure_of/

Answer (score 6):

For installing :

1. `sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev libglew-dev`
2. `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

For linking :

```
 g++ .... -lglut -lGL ....
```