# Why freeglut3-dev doesn't provide .pc file for pkg-config?

Tags: cmake, debian, freeglut, pkg-config

Why latest *Debian's Sid* (*Sid*, which is after *Debian Buster 10.0*) testing repositories doesn't contain [.pc](http://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html#concepts) file for [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config)?

Result of `dpkg -L freeglut3-dev`:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/GL
/usr/include/GL/glut.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_std.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut_ext.h
/usr/include/GL/freeglut.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.a
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/index.html
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/progress.html
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/ogl_sm.png
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/download.html
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/freeglut_user_interface.html
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/freeglut_logo.png
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/freeglut.html
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/structure.html
/usr/share/doc/freeglut3-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so
```

Note that in [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/)'s repository there is [freeglut.pc.in](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/freeglut.pc.in) file and is included in [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/CMakeLists.txt).

I know that there are some [threads](http://sourceforge.net/p/freeglut/bugs/search/?q=pkg-config) about this issue, but they don't refer to any *Linux* distribution.

Related question: [installing Freeglut on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318510/installing-freeglut-on-linux).

Comment: This post is more appropriate for Debian bugtracker, isn't it?

Comment: Someone already [posted](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=575025) it on *Debian* bugtracker.

Comment: BTW: Lack of *.pc* file for *freeglut* isn't big problem, because *CMake* has GLUT's [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) [module](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGLUT.cmake) (which is preferred). You can check it running `cmake --help-module-list | grep -i glut`.

Comment: Lack of *.pc* file is actually a problem if you build project *without CMake*.